# textarea not clearing on keypress using jQuery

Tags: jquery

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).on("keypress", ".admin-msg-box textarea", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            var msg = $(this).val();

            var c_id = $(this).closest('.msg_box').find('.msg_head').data('c_id');

            if ($.trim(msg).length !== 0) {
                  saveAdminMsg(c_id,msg);
                $('<div class="msg_a temp_msg">' + msg + '</div>').insertBefore('.msg_push');
                $('.msg_body').scrollTop($('.msg_body')[0].scrollHeight);
            }
        }
    });
```

It should clear textarea after pressing ENTER. But it contains old text and if I press ENTER again it append old text again. It should be mentioned that textarea is created dynamically.

Comment: Is my answer below, what you was looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing the resetting of the `textarea` and `msg` variable:

```
$(this).val("");
msg = "";
```

Check the following example below:

```js
$("#appendHere").append('<div class="admin-msg-box"><textarea></textarea></div>');

$(document).on("keypress", ".admin-msg-box textarea", function (e) {

        if (e.keyCode == 13) 
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            var msg = $(this).val();
            
            //var c_id = $(this).closest('.msg_box').find('.msg_head').data('c_id');
  
            if ($.trim(msg).length !== 0)
            {
                //saveAdminMsg(c_id,msg);
                //$('<div class="msg_a temp_msg">' + msg + '</div>').insertBefore('.msg_push');
                //$('.msg_body').scrollTop($('.msg_body')[0].scrollHeight);
              alert(msg);
            }
          
          $(this).val("");
          msg = "";
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="appendHere"></div>
```

**Addition to this answer:**

I've added `e.preventDefault();` so when you press enter, it won't add a new line to the `textarea`.